# Writing an R function for a vector of values

Tags: r, function

Any tips on writing a function in R where:
An original score (e.g. 50) is adjusted according to a 2nd score for several individuals?
First score is 50, and the second score is in a vector ranging from 1 to 5;  if the second score is 1 then -5 is added to 50, if it is 2 then -2.5 is added, if 3 then 0 is added, if 4 then 2.5 is added, and if 5 then 5 is added to the original score of 50.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more suited to your need:

```
any_tips <- function(x, score = 50) {
  df <- tibble::tibble(sscore = x)
  df <- df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
      score = dplyr::case_when(
        sscore == 1 ~ score - 5,
        sscore == 2 ~ score - 2.5,
        sscore == 3 ~ score,
        sscore == 4 ~ score + 2.5,
        sscore == 5 ~ score + 5
      )
    )
  df
}

> any_tips(1:5)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  sscore score
   <int> <dbl>
1      1  45  
2      2  47.5
3      3  50  
4      4  52.5
5      5  55  
>
```

If you still have something different in mind please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I am slowly developing my R skills and get tripped up on little coding errors on this basic function: the output from this code isn't quite what i am after ... i'd like to be able to submit a string of say 4 different secondary scores and get their final scores as per the values of x above -- e.g.  submitting c(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5) , the output would be scores of 45 47.5 50 52.5 55

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I just changed my code, hopefully this is what you are looking for.